# Woocommerce empty cart button in header

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently developing a Wordpress + Woocommerce website and I have a Login/Register + Cart Info in a menu on top of the header. 
My problem is that whenever I click the button, it redirects me to the "Cart is empty page" . Instead, I want it only to empty the cart, without any redirection. I have tried variants with the wp_redirect() function, but it kinda' beats me. Can anyone help? I would be much appreciated.

The function looks like

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );

function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
   global $woocommerce;
   if ( isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) {
      $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
      wp_redirect(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
}
```

The HTML for the button looks like this:

```
<a class="empty-cart-button" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>?empty-cart"><?php _e( 'Empty Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
```

Cheerio!

Comment: It seem that your issue is related to your theme's header. The authors of the theme you are using have surely customized woocommerce mini cart widget functionality, because what you are describing is not a WooCommerce normal behavior for mini cart. It looks like a theme related bug. So the best thing to do is to contact your theme author's support threads and to open a support thread or ticket.

Comment: I have managed to empty the cart changing the href of the anchor tag into get_permalink(), but I want the page not to reload at all. It seems that the "?empty-cart" at the end of the anchor tag is doing the job. I also tried to do this with an input, but it ain't working. It doesn't seem like a theme bug to me, everything else works fine and I have never had problems with the theme before. It's a personal child theme for the Divi Theme :(

Comment: So this is a customization you have maid… thats why not?